# C# ASP.NET CORE WEB API headless ARRAY deserialization struggle

Tags: c#, soap, deserialization, datacontract

i have a strugle to construct DATACONTRACT class for deserialization of SOAP response:

```
     <matches>
        <item>
          <emdrId>66.19.121.000000301</emdrId>
          <localUid>3ece0f3e-f691-4a6d-bc16-4f34805d97d8</localUid>
          <registrationDate>2019-02-08T00:00:00+03:00</registrationDate>
          <registrationDateTime>2019-02-08T10:40:00.612+03:00</registrationDateTime>
          <storeTillDate>2039-01-30T21:00:00+00:00</storeTillDate>
        </item>
        <item>
          <emdrId>66.22.5036.001854228</emdrId>
          <localUid>86689ddd-597b-4de4-af07-f565713635ab</localUid>
          <registrationDate>2022-10-18T00:00:00+03:00</registrationDate>
          <registrationDateTime>2022-10-18T17:07:11.632+03:00</registrationDateTime>
          <storeTillDate>2047-10-17T21:00:00+00:00</storeTillDate>
        </item>
        <page>
          <itemsPerPage>1000</itemsPerPage>
          <hasNext>false</hasNext>
        </page>
      </matches>
```

I try next clases:

```
    [DataContract(Namespace = "blah blah blah")]
    public class SearchMatches
    {
        [DataMember] public searchMatch[]? item { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public MatchesPage? page { get; set; }
    }
```

And with custom collection:

```
    [DataContract(Namespace = "blah blah blah")]
    public class SearchMatches
    {
        [DataMember] public ArrayOfsearchMatch? item { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public MatchesPage? page { get; set; }
    }

    [CollectionDataContract(ItemName = "item", Namespace = "blah blah blah")]
    public class ArrayOfsearchMatch : List<searchMatch> { }
```

The problem is object <MATCHES> have list of <ITEM> and <PAGE> object. And list of <ITEM> didnt have wrapt element like <ITEMS>

All i have in results is:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "matches": {
    "item": [],
    "page": {
      "itemsPerPage": 1000,
      "hasNext": false
    }
  },
  "errors": null
}
```

Deserializer get <PAGE> and <STATUS> but item element didnt filled with data

Heres my searchMatch and MatchesPage clases:

```
    [DataContract(Namespace = "blah blah blah")]
    public class searchMatch
    {
        [DataMember] public string? emdrId { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public string? localUid { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public DateTimeOffset? registrationDate { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public DateTimeOffset? registrationDateTime { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public DateTime? storeTillDate { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "blah blah blah")]
    public partial class MatchesPage : object
    {
        [DataMember] public int itemsPerPage { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public bool hasNext { get; set; }
    }
```

Plz help me.... i wanna go home......

I googled like 3 days at now

Comment: What is complete XML response?  Does response have namespace?

Comment: Data contract on server have namespace and i show them in class, for privacy blanked them with "blah blah blah".

Comment: I cannot tell what is wrong without all the info.  The issue can be caused by a number of different things being wrong.  I do not want to go down the wrong track.

Comment: <searchRegistryItemResponse>
  <status></status>
  <matches>
 <item>
   <emdrId></emdrId>
   <localUid></localUid>
   <registrationDate></registrationDate>
   <registrationDateTime></registrationDateTime>
   <storeTillDate></storeTillDate>
 </item>
 <item>
   <emdrId></emdrId>
   <localUid></localUid>
   <registrationDate></registrationDate>
   <registrationDateTime></registrationDateTime>
   <storeTillDate></storeTillDate>
 </item>
 <page>
   <itemsPerPage></itemsPerPage>
   <hasNext></hasNext>
 </page>
  </matches>
</searchRegistryItemResponse>

Comment: There are no namespaces in what you jut posted.  Your classes have namespaces that you may need to remove.

Comment: @jdweng why is namespace is imtortant? i have response and need to deserialize it on xml rules. BTW i checked XSD schema of not mapping class searchMatch. It have nillable element with minoccur=1 documentVersion that completly miss in server response that a get from fiddler. Can it be service fault?

Comment: @jdweng sorry i am a newbee here and cant chat with u to send full WSDL and responce....

Comment: The library requires the namespace to match or if there is not just do not include the namespace.  The library ignores tags that are missing in either classes or input except if the schema requires the value.  Like minoccur = 1.

Comment: @jdweng if i change searchMatch[]? to searchMatch? it correct fill from first item of responce.

Comment: Try adding above the line [XmlElement()].  XmlSerialization for arrays by default expects two XML tags.  Adding XmlElement above the line changes the default from two tags to one tag.

Comment: @jdweng i marked <matches> as array of "searchMatch" insted of "SearchMatches" type with array and  "page" item aaaaand - it worker. Array filler with items none. BUT.... i lost <page> element, that comes in <matches> nodes after "searchMatch" items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code should look like this

```
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement("matches")]
        public Matches matches { get; set; }
    }
    public class Matches
    {
        [XmlElement("item")]
        public Item[] item { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("page")]
        public Page page { get; set; }
    }
    public class Item
    {
    }
    public class Page
    {
    }
```